# Match only parenthesis with text and numbers in R

Tags: r, regex, string-matching

I would like to replace the parenthesis and the text between parenthesis in string variables. However I only want to replace those parenthesis with at least one number in it.

Example string:

```
text <- c("Sekretär (dipl.) (G3)", "Zolldeklarant (3 Jahre)", "Grenzwächter (< 2 Jahre)")
```

I tried the following:

```
str_extract_all(text, " *\\(.*?\\d+.*?\\) *")
```

It does extract the text in parenthesis, but in the first one, it matches also the first parenthesis without any number.

The extraction should look like:

```
" (G3)"
" (3 Jahre)"  
" (< 2 Jahre)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *replace* these terms in parentheses, containing at least one number, then `sub` is a good base R option:

```
text
sapply(text, function (x) {
    gsub("\\([^()]*\\d[^()]*\\)", "REMOVED", x)
})

[1] "Sekretär (dipl.) (G3)"    "Zolldeklarant (3 Jahre)" "Grenzwächter (< 2 Jahre)"
[1] "Sekretär (dipl.) REMOVED"    "Zolldeklarant REMOVED" "Grenzwächter REMOVED"
```

I have replaced with the literal text `REMOVED` just as a placeholder to show the replacement.

**Edit:**

If you just want to extract these terms, we can also use `sub` for this:

```
sapply(text, function (x) {
    gsub(".*(\\([^()]*\\d[^()]*\\)).*", "\\1", x)
})

[1] "(G3)" "(3 Jahre)" "(< 2 Jahre)"
```

Here, we capture the term in parentheses, then replace the entire string with just the first (and only) capture group `\\1`.

Comment: @Jan I am also not sure, but it would be strange if "replace" means something other than what that word actually means.  In any case, I added an update which covers this possibility.

Comment: @K.Schupbach: If it works for you, consider accepting and upvoting the given answers (arrow, tick on the left).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\([^()]*\d+[^()]*\)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/o1A49R/1/).
Backslashes need to be double escaped in `R`, so your expression would become

```
\\([^()]*\\d+[^()]*\\)
```

---

Broken down this is

```
\(     # (
[^()]* # not ( nor ), 0+ times
\d+    # digits, 1+
[^()]* # same as above
\)     # )
```

Comment: There's one backlash missing before d+ (for R): \\([^()]*\\d+[^()]*\\)  Otherwise perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
text <- c("Sekretär (dipl.) (G3)", "Zolldeklarant (3 Jahre)", "Grenzwächter (< 2 Jahre)")
gsub(".*\\((.*[0-9].*)\\).*","(\\1)",text)
```

Basically you ask gsub to select the whole string but to assign as a group (\1) the strings in a parentheses and including a number.

Plus, if you want to extract the last parentheses always, that could follow a different approach.